# Problem with google maps subway stations

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to find nearby subway station from the specified point in nyc. I am trying to use google maps api, I found some examples how to get nearby streets or place names etc. but can't find stations.

I think there can be two ways of doing this:

1. if I find list of subway stations with coordinates (latitude, longitude) I can write script that will tell me which of the stations are in the radius for example 1 mile.
2. Google has subway stations on the map, I think there should be some way to get coordinates of those stations directly from google, even better would be if google will find nearby stations for me.

Comment: Is there any solution now? How can we retrieve subway station's data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no current way to get Points of interests (POI) on a Google API Map

Answer (score 0):

i think it is possible (now 2014) to get lat, lon for subway stations using Googles Places Library. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21286912/701702