# Google Maps: Retrieve nearby subway station's latitude and longitude?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When viewing google maps for New York, We can see many metro stations. How can I get nearby Metro station's data?

For example, I send a request contain the latitude and longitude of my location and a radius of distance, it would return subway station within the given distance

Comment: Did my answer help you @cqcn1991 ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) for this. By feeding in the `type` into the request. You can view the [supported types here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types)

```
var request = {
  location: pyrmont,
  radius: '500',
  types: ['subway_station', 'train_station']
};
```

Although I dunno how to get which metro lines are available at the station.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) to query for this data.  Lat/Lon and radius are both parameters to this API and you can specify a text search like "Subway"

Comment: Using text search with "Subway" will also return results with name "SUBWAY® Restaurants". Maybe better approach is to use `nearbySearch` or `radarSearch` with `types: ['subway_station']`