# Google Maps: Retrieve nearby subway stations and their subway line info

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I've seen that you can retrieve nearby subway stations for a location using the Google Maps Places API, as explained here:

[Google Maps: Retrieve nearby subway station's latitude and longtitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249023/google-maps-retrieve-nearby-subway-stations-latitude-and-longtitude)

But in addition to that data, I would also like to retrieve the **subway lines** available at that station. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the Places API doesn't expose this information for transit stations. There is a feature request in Google issue tracker to make it possible to retrieve lines numbers for each stop. You can find this feature request at

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827961

Please feel free to star this feature request to express your interest and subscribe to further notifications from Google.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I guess until this becomes possible, I'll download a list of stations and their lines separately and try to complete the data based on that.

Comment: Hi, did you find that list of stations by any chance? I'm in the same predicament as you were ...

Comment: If you happen to be in NY, looks like there are NYC Open Data sets for this. See: https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/nyc-subway-locator