# Is there a way to get train lines that connect to a given Place of type 'train_station'

Tags: google-places-api

I can use the Places API to get train stations in some radius. Can I then get the lines that are connected to each station somehow?

Comment: Currently this information is not exposed via Places API. Corresponding feature request in Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827961

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [Google Maps: Retrieve nearby subway stations and their subway line info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594724/google-maps-retrieve-nearby-subway-stations-and-their-subway-line-info)